# DropdownButton - don't show popup on tap

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown, tap

I want to show my own page on dropdown button tap, then item selected on page should be set as dropdown button value.

So basically, I need DropdownButton without any popup on tap. When I use `onTap` still default popup will be shown, how to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use a button instead? or you can try to create an Inkwell put a container on its child and make it look like a button and write your code inside Inkwell OnTap(){}

Answer (score 0):

1- Pass null to `items` parameter to disable the button.

2- You'll notice icon's color will be grey with disabled button, you can change it by setting `color` of the icon you send to `icon` parameter or send color directly to `iconDisabledColor` parameter.

3- You'll not use `value` parameter, instead you'll just use `hint` to show both your hint and your value. and update it using your state management after you pick new value from your own page.

4- Wrap your DropdownButton with `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` to show your own page when you tap on the button.

5- If you want to customize your DropdownButton shape, size and more. You can try my new package [DropdownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2). It's simple, easy, based on Flutter's core DropdownButton and have lots of features.